# data annotation disallowing numbers only strings ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: c#, string, asp.net-mvc-4, numbers, data-annotations

How would one create a data annotation that only allows string that either have letters and numbers or letters only.

Basically disallow number only strings.

Right now, I have a letter only validation and I can't find out how to also allow numbers IF there are letters present in the string.

`[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "No numbers allowed in the sequence.")]`

Thanks!

**EDIT - Found a solution!**

Basicall:

`[0-9]*[A-z ]+[0-9]*`

This regex works *ALMOST* perfectly...

It catches an error if the users enters a number-only string, but...
If he adds a single space, he can get away with the string.

To prevent that little error, I simply catch any empty spaces in my POST method from my controller and add an error to the ModelState.

Thanks to @PhillipBetts for the Regex 101 link, which helped me solve this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of resources out there to test and learn Regex. My favourite [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/).

It also has a library that you can search and find useful Regex. It also gives a handy explanation.

Anyway, hopefully this is what you're looking for :

```
^[\w ]+$
```

Comment: Problem is, a string like `1asdf` or `asdf1` should be valid. Can't use that.

Comment: Yeah, he only wants to reject strings which have only numbers. A string which has both characters and numbers is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to change your regular expression to `\D` to indicate there is at least one non-digit.

Comment: That didn't do the trick sadly.
It doesn't seem to be picking up any value with this.

Comment: @Raspberry weird - it will work fine in a `Regex.Matches` - you may want to play around with it a bit.

Comment: Well, what I meant is that, as soon as I enter a number, I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

you should try the String contains method with your regex

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hmmm, that would imply that I would have to check the value in the controller, I am trying to find a way to get a working data annotation.